# export results from MATLAB under MATLAB using multiple loops into different sheets of an Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to export MATLAB results running in multiple loops to different sheets of a `csv` file. For instance, for `(i,j) = (1,1)`, the results will be saved in sheet 1; for `(i,j) = (1,2)`, the results will be saved in sheet 2, and so on.

I have done this process for a single loop. For example

```
for c = 1:5
    xlswrite('OPTION3',classinfo1,c,'C');
    xlswrite('OPTION3',classinfo2,c,'D');  
end
```

But when I have multiple loops:

```
 for i = 1:4
   for j = 1:3
        xlswrite('OPTION3',classinfo1,(i:j),'C');
        xlswrite('OPTION3',classinfo2,(i:j),'D'); 
   end
 end
```

It is throwing me an error message:

> > Error using xlswrite (line 172)
> >     Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: [`Sheet`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#inputarg_sheet) must be a character vector, string, or positive integer.

Comment: @beesleep  I used the above code and i got close to what i want. When i ran the code i see first three sheets are empty with a total of 12 sheets generated. I figured out because of the "4-1". Also i want to generalize "(4-1)". How do you think i can do that. in my case i = 1: length(A). Do you think i should put i+j*(length(A)-1)?